# Eclipse Paho MQTT client in Java using TLS

Tags: java, mqtt, tls1.2, paho

I need to create an MQTT client in Java usign the [Eclipse Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/java/index.php#:%7E:text=%20Eclipse%20Paho%20Java%20Client%20%201%20Features.,sample%20that%20connects%20to%20%20a...%20More%20).

My MQTT Broker stands behind an Nginx TCP reverse proxy, which has TLS enabled. Therefore, I need to configure the client to use TLS.

Nevertheless, I don't want to provide my client with a certificate (I don't think I really need to, since I can connect with a NodeRED MQTT client with TLS enabled and this client is not provided any certificate; the same - I am told - with a .NET Core client).

Is it possible to do this with Eclipse Paho library?
All the examples I can find make use of a certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just need to provide `ssl://` or `mqtts://` URL instead of a `tcp://` or `mqtt://`

e.g. using the example on Paho Java client [page](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/java/index.php):

```
String topic        = "MQTT Examples";
String content      = "Message from MqttPublishSample";
int qos             = 2;
String broker       = "tcp://mqtt.eclipse.org:1883";
String clientId     = "JavaSample";
MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
```

You just need to change the `broker` String to:

```
String broker       = "ssl://mqtt.eclipse.org:8883";
```

This assumes that nginx is listening on port 8883 and that the broker is using a certifacte signed by a public trusted CA.

All this is also described in the Javadoc [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttClient.html#MqttClient-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very quick answer. 
Just two remarks.
1) The MQTT Broker is not configured to use a certificate at all, the Nginx is the only one with a TLS certificate.
2) I tried the Paho Java client example with the suggested modification as you reported it above and I got an Exception of type `MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed`.

Comment: As far as the client is concerned nginx is the broker. The second point is because you are not using a certificate from a real CA. You will need to add the CA cert to a trust store and supply a custom SSLSocketFactory

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the remark about the client and the Nginx, it is clear what you say.
I will very soon try to set up and provide a custom `SSLSocketFactory` and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: This is a running example of what @hardillb said: https://github.com/iakko/mqtt-paho-tls-example. This addresses also the issue on the SSLHandshakeException.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the remark and the pointing, @iakko!